# Why do I need double pointers for an array of objects? HashMap Example in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

I am practicing some C++ and I was confused about why I need double pointers for an array of objects(such as a node struct). Here is a simple code snippet to explain my situation:

```
struct HashNode{

    HashNode* next;
    int data;
    int key;
    int hashCode;

    HashNode::HashNode(
        HashNode* next, 
        const int& data, 
        const int& key, 
        const int& hashCode
        ) : next(next), data(data), key(key), hashCode(hashCode)
        {}

};

class HashMap{
    public:
        HashMap();
        HashMap(int tableSize);
        ~HashMap();

    private:
        //Here is the double pointer
        HashNode** table;
};

HashMap::HashMap(){
    //Here is the array initialization 
    table = new HashNode*[100];
}
```

I have removed the code that is unnecessary for the question.

If I remove the double pointer as such:

```
HashNode* table;
```

and

```
table = new HashNode[100];
```

I get the following error.

```
hashmap.cpp: In method `HashMap::HashMap()':
hashmap.cpp:87: no matching function for call to `HashNode::HashNode ()'
hashmap.cpp:61: candidates are: HashNode::HashNode(const HashNode &)
hashmap.cpp:58:                 HashNode::HashNode(HashNode *, const int &, cons
t int &, const int &)
```

which shows me that the HashNode tries to run a constructor.

If I change only the initialization of the array as `table = new HashNode*[100];` while keeping `HashNode* table;` then I get the following error.

```
hashmap.cpp: In method `HashMap::HashMap()':
hashmap.cpp:87: assignment to `HashNode *' from `HashNode **'
```

My assumption is that when I make an array of objects, I need the lifetime of the objects to be for the duration of the program as well. This requires me to use pointers for the objects as well as the array. Therefore, I need to have double pointers for the array since it points to pointers and I need pointers for the objects.

However, I am still unsure and I cannot really find any good explanations online. Could someone please explain this situation?

Comment: You need to read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Is this a bad question to ask here? I thought it was a nice example and I hadn't grasped the concept. I will look into the books thank you!

Comment: The question _format_ is not bad, just the triviality of it. There is one particular requirement that is not met: put in as much effort as humanly possible into researching before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation uses [separate chaining with linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists) for managing hash collisions. Therefore, `table` is an array of pointers to `HashNode`, meaning that it needs two asterisks:

- One asterisk comes from the type of array element, which is `HashNode*`
- The other asterisk comes from making an array of `HashNode*`

That is also why you have an asterisk in the `new` expression:

```
table = new HashNode*[100];
//                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are very new to c++ pointers.
What you are currently doing is make array of 100 pointers. So Compiler is not giving you any error because actual objects are not created with this line.
**HashNode **table = new HashNode*[100];**

But when you use 
**HashNode *table = new HashNode[100];**
Then you are trying to create 100 objects for HashNode;
But you do not have default constructor so compiler giving you the above error.

I have attached following working code. check it out.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    struct HashNode{

        HashNode* next;
        int data;
        int key;
        int hashCode;

        HashNode(){}

        HashNode(
            HashNode* next, 
            const int& data, 
            const int& key, 
            const int& hashCode
            ) : next(next), data(data), key(key), hashCode(hashCode)
            {}

    };

    class HashMap{
        public:
            HashMap();

        private:
            //Here is the double pointer
            HashNode* table;
    };

    HashMap::HashMap(){
        //Here is the array initialization 
        table = new HashNode[100];
    }

    int main() {
        // your code goes here

        HashMap ob;
        std::cout << "him" <<  std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are declaring array of pointers

> HashNode** table;

That is an array named table with pointers of the type hashNode.